# How to do mathematical manipulation work on extracted numbers from a string

Tags: r, replace

I have a data set as shown below:

```
structure(list(Commission20 = c("3.3% AND 1.2%", "3.2% 1S $100000 1.1% BALANCE", 
"3.2% AND 1.0% AND 1.1% AND $1000 SELLING BONUS", "3.3% AND 1.2%", 
"3.3% AND 1.2%", "3.0% AND 1.0% BALANCE", "3.2% 1S $100000 1.1% BALANCE", 
"3.2% AND 1.2%", "3.2% AND 1.2%", "3.2% 1ST 1OOK AND 1.1% BALANCE", 
"3.2% AND 1.1%", "3.0% 1ST $100000", "3.0% 1ST $100000", "3.2% 1ST $100000", 
"3.0% 1ST $100000", "3.0% 1ST $100000", "3.0% 1ST $100000", "3.0% 1ST $100000", 
"3.2% 1ST $100000 AND $5000"), First = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_), `cut-off` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_), Second = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_), Bonus = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_), Fixed = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_)), row.names = c(NA, -19L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

As can be seen, some data are in the form of **3.0% 1ST $100000** (I am only interested in this form for now). Obviously, this number is simply $3000, so I want to calculate 3000 and replace it instead of NA value in **fixed** column. So, not only should I extract 3% and $100000, but also I have to multiply these and calculate 3000 and replace it in the proper column. The expected result is then like this:

```
   Commission20                                   First `cut-off` Second Bonus Fixed
   <chr>                                          <chr> <chr>     <chr>  <chr> <chr>
 1 3.3% AND 1.2%                                  NA    NA        NA     NA    NA   
 2 3.2% 1S $100000 1.1% BALANCE                   NA    NA        NA     NA    NA   
 3 3.2% AND 1.0% AND 1.1% AND $1000 SELLING BONUS NA    NA        NA     NA    NA   
 4 3.3% AND 1.2%                                  NA    NA        NA     NA    NA   
 5 3.3% AND 1.2%                                  NA    NA        NA     NA    NA   
 6 3.0% AND 1.0% BALANCE                          NA    NA        NA     NA    NA   
 7 3.2% 1S $100000 1.1% BALANCE                   NA    NA        NA     NA    NA   
 8 3.2% AND 1.2%                                  NA    NA        NA     NA    NA   
 9 3.2% AND 1.2%                                  NA    NA        NA     NA    NA   
10 3.2% 1ST 1OOK AND 1.1% BALANCE                 NA    NA        NA     NA    NA   
11 3.2% AND 1.1%                                  NA    NA        NA     NA    NA   
12 3.0% 1ST $100000                               NA    NA        NA     NA    3000   
13 3.0% 1ST $100000                               NA    NA        NA     NA    3000   
14 3.2% 1ST $100000                               NA    NA        NA     NA    3200   
15 3.0% 1ST $100000                               NA    NA        NA     NA    3000   
16 3.0% 1ST $100000                               NA    NA        NA     NA    3000   
17 3.0% 1ST $100000                               NA    NA        NA     NA    3000   
18 3.0% 1ST $100000                               NA    NA        NA     NA    3000
19 3.2% 1ST $100000 AND $5000                     NA    NA        NA     NA    NA
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code just focuses on the rows with "**percent% 1ST $dollars**" format in "Commission20" entries:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(stringr) # allows you to manipulate patterns from strings

df %>% 
    mutate(
        percent = as.numeric(str_extract(Commission20, "^\\d\\.\\d")), 
        dollars = as.numeric(sub("T \\$", "", str_extract(Commission20, "T \\$\\d+$"))), 
        Fixed = percent/100 * dollars) %>% 
    select(-c(percent, dollars))
```

This code creates temporary columns to store the extracted percent and dollars from the "Commmission20". It then uses those numbers to calculate "Fixed" values.

The `stringr` package can be a useful tool here (for string manipulations). This [cheat sheet](https://github.com/rstudio/cheatsheets/blob/master/strings.pdf) may come in handy if you need to work on the other commission entries.